# represent a help table in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Table 1: Articles

Table 2: ArticleCategories

how do I represent the relationship between the two tables which is a 1->1 relationship:

I can do the following, but I'm not sure it's the correct way :

```
public class Article
{
    public int ArticleIndex { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public Guid User { get; set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateExpires { get; set; }
    public bool Show { get; set; }   
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleHtml { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ContentHtml { get; set; }
    public string ShortTitle { get; set; }
    public ArticleCategory Category { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleCategory
{
    public int CategoryIndex { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yes ............................................

Comment: Don't you mean a 1->Many relationship? *One* category has *many* articles and an article belongs to *one* category?

Comment: you are right, my bad ... it is a one to many relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By convention, Code First expects an `Id` property for each class/table. Then you can do something like this:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ArticleIndex { get; set; }
    public int Category { get; set; }
    public Guid User { get; set; }
    public int Parent { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateExpires { get; set; }
    public bool Show { get; set; }   
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleHtml { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string ContentHtml { get; set; }
    public string ShortTitle { get; set; }
    public int ArticleCategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ArticleCategory ArticleCategory { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CategoryIndex { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}
```

Note the `virtual` keyword. EF Code First needs this so it can perform its magic behind the scenes.

Now, if you are working with an `Article`, you can get all it's category info by doing `article.ArticleCategory`, and if you have an `ArticleCategory` you can find out what article it refers to with `articleCategory.Articles.Single()`.

For more info, see this article by Scott Gu:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/08/announcing-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-release.aspx